# How Could I Model a Class With Arbitrary Hierarchy?

Tags: c#, .net

Consider the following XML:

```
<elements>
    <element attribute="value1">
        <or>
            <subelement attribute="value2" />
            <subelement attribute="value3" />
        </or>
    </element>
    <element attribute="value">
        <and>
            <subelement attribute="value4" />
            <subelement attribute="value5" />
            <or>
                <subelement attribute="value6" />
                <subelement attribute="value7" />
            </or>
        </and>
    </element>
</elements>
```

Note that the following is also valid:

```
<elements>
    <element attribute="value1">
        <subelement attribute="value2" />
    </element>
</elements>
```

And so is this:

```
<elements>
    <element attribute="value1">
        <and>
            <or>
                <subelement attribute="value2" />
                <subelement attribute="value3" />
            </or>
            <or>
                <subelement attribute="value4" />
                <subelement attribute="value5" />
            </or>
        </and>
    </element>
</elements>
```

(The above example would equate to (value2 or value3) AND (value4 or value5)

I tried using xsd.exe to create a XSD file from the XML and then a .cs class but it was not sufficient for my needs as I need something that can have an arbitrary depth.

How would I model this in C# as classes? I'm thinking perhaps along the lines of some sort of fluent builder pattern?

Thanks,

Richard

P.s. Anyone who can come up with a way to validate the rules created by such a class structure gets a /hug :)

Comment: Yes, I looked into that but my head exploded. I hear this is common when investigating expression trees :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following schema definition correctly validates all 3 of your XML examples. Unfortunately `XSD.exe` crashes with a stack overflow exception when it tries to turn it in to C# code. However setting the xsd file as the schema [inside visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161224/xml-validation-with-xsd-in-visual-studio-ide) makes the xml editor work correctly and will point out any validation rules that your xml violates.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="schema"
    targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/schema.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/schema.xsd"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/schema.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
  <xs:element name="elements">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name ="element" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice>
              <xs:element name="and" type="subLogic"/>
              <xs:element name="or" type="subLogic"/>
              <xs:element name="subelement" type ="subElement" />
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:attribute name="attribute"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="subLogic">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="subelement" type="subElement"/>
      <xs:element name="and" type="subLogic"/>
      <xs:element name="or" type="subLogic"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="subElement">
    <xs:attribute name="attribute"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Here is a changed version of the xml to make visual studio validate it and enables intellisense. Just be shure you have your xsd file selected under the `schemas` selector in the properites for the xml file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<elements 
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/schema.xsd"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/schema.xsd">
  <element  attribute="value1">
    <and>
      <or>
        <subelement attribute="value2" />
        <subelement attribute="value3" />
      </or>
      <or>
        <subelement attribute="value4" />
        <subelement attribute="value5" />
      </or>
    </and>
  </element>
</elements>
```

Without knowing more of what you are representing or what the classes will need to do here is a basic layout that mimic's the XSD. XML you generate from this class will likely not validate, but it is just a matter of adding the correct attributes to the classes and properties so everything shows up with the correct name, the layout is correct.

```xml
class SubLogic
{
}

abstract class CollectionType : SubLogic
{
    public SubLogic[] Sub { get; set; }
}

class And : CollectionType
{
}

class Or : CollectionType
{
}

class SubElement : SubLogic
{
    public string Attribute { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("elements")]
class ElementCollection
{
    public Element[] Elements {Get;Set}
}

class Element
{
    public SubLogic Sub { Get; set;}
}
```