# Unable to get Intellisense work while editing XML files in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xsd, intellisense, xsd-validation

I am trying to make Intellisense work for my XML files but unable to do so. In the properties of my XML files I have specified `wss.xsd` in `Scehmas` attribute. But still no suggestions for tag or attributes show up while editing XML file. I followed the steps suggested in [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3161224/1047998).

And the strange thing is that I cannot edit my `Schemas` attribute for properties for XML file. It always includes these XSD files:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\15\TEMPLATE\XML\CamlQuery.xsd
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\15\TEMPLATE\XML\camlview.xsd
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\15\TEMPLATE\XML\coredefinitions.xsd
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\15\TEMPLATE\XML\cui.xsd
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\15\TEMPLATE\XML\wss.xsd
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\15\TEMPLATE\XML\CamlQuery.xsd
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\15\TEMPLATE\XML\camlview.xsd
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\15\TEMPLATE\XML\coredefinitions.xsd
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\15\TEMPLATE\XML\cui.xsd
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\15\TEMPLATE\XML\wss.xsd
```

[image]

If I unmark the schemas from `Use` column, click on OK button and again option the dialog the schema is again checked.

I addition I can see errors in my XML file like `The attributeGroup 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/:invocationTagAttributeGroup' has already been declared.` which I believe is because of so many CSD files as schemas.

Does anyone know why is this happening?

I am using SharePoint 2013 and Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate edition.

Comment: I have a similar problem... even clicking the `Remove` button is ineffective. I don't even have SharePoint!

Answer (score 0):

In the root element of your xml you should have the attribute `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint"`. Remove any other xmlns attributes while you are debugging this.

Comment: The root element looks like this `<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="EmployeeList" FolderCreation="FALSE" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" Url="Lists/EmployeeList" BaseType="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">`. It has `xmlns` attribute and `xmlns:ows` attribute as well. I removed the `xmlns:ows` attribute but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you try checking "use" on only one of the sharepoint schemas in vs?

Comment: That is another problem I am facing which I mentioned in my question. I am unable modify my `Use` column. I uncheck them click on OK and if I open it again all the checks are there as is.

Comment: can you click remove?

Comment: Tried it and it comes back again. Ran Visual Studio as administrator but still the same issue. This is really weird.

Answer (score 0):

**Didn't fully solve the issue!**

I finally renamed the folder:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\XML
```

to something like `"XML - removed to avoid use in VS2013"`

As soon as it was renamed, the Visual Studio editor stopped trying to use those XSD files.

Comment: So after this VS uses `wss.xsd` and Intellisense works?

Comment: :( It seemed to for a while, then all the XML intellisense seemed to be gone. I had to restore that folder, and will have to live with the Sharepoint XSD interfering in the editor.