# Disable warnings for specific files in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have some files in my C# WPF project with Build Action set to Content. But these files don't contain C# code. Unfortunatelly, these files generates a lot of Warnings in Error List. How can I set these non-c# files to be ignored in "VS Warnig Analyzer"? I tried use Exclude from StyleCop, but warnings are still here...

EDIT:
Example warnings (there is 1623 warnings for single .pak file)

```
Warning 498 Attribute ' C:\Users\Dominik\Projects\slidessync\SlidesSync\SlidesSync\cef.pak  41526   1   SlidesDrive.Windows
Warning 514 Attribute ' C:\Users\Dominik\Projects\slidessync\SlidesSync\SlidesSync\cef.pak  41472   17  SlidesDrive.Windows
Warning 538 Attribute ' C:\Users\Dominik\Projects\slidessync\SlidesSync\SlidesSync\cef.pak  41224   1   SlidesDrive.Windows
Warning 548 Attribute ' C:\Users\Dominik\Projects\slidessync\SlidesSync\SlidesSync\cef.pak  41194   1   SlidesDrive.Windows
Warning 549 Attribute ' C:\Users\Dominik\Projects\slidessync\SlidesSync\SlidesSync\cef.pak  41196   1   SlidesDrive.Windows
Warning 126 Attribute '�' already exists.   C:\Users\Dominik\Projects\slidessync\SlidesSync\SlidesSync\cef.pak  41208   1   SlidesDrive.Windows
Warning 132 Attribute '�' already exists.   C:\Users\Dominik\Projects\slidessync\SlidesSync\SlidesSync\cef.pak  41213   1071    SlidesDrive.Windows
Warning 210 Attribute '�' already exists.   C:\Users\Dominik\Projects\slidessync\SlidesSync\SlidesSync\cef.pak  41911   1   SlidesDrive.Windows
Warning 211 Attribute '�' already exists.   C:\Users\Dominik\Projects\slidessync\SlidesSync\SlidesSync\cef.pak  41912   87  SlidesDrive.Windows
Warning 222 Attribute '�' already exists.   C:\Users\Dominik\Projects\slidessync\SlidesSync\SlidesSync\cef.pak  41925   1   SlidesDrive.Windows
```

Comment: post the warnings here to help us understand the problem.

Comment: Ok, I attached warnings

Comment: oh, thanks, after I closed this file, warnings goes out.. my fail, sorry :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems to me these files are XML files, or another file type that Visual Studio recognizes. Visual Studio tries to check them if you open them (they don't have a compile time impact on warnings / errors). You can close them and the warnings will be gone.

You should probably:

- Fix the issues if you can: double attributes are a bad idea. Use elements instead.
- For XML: [Add the XSD to Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161224/xml-validation-with-xsd-in-visual-studio-ide) to let Visual Studio correctly validate the XML file.

Comment: no, no these files are not XML, these are files with combined mixed languges (HTML, CSS, binary data, some scripting language) for some 3rd library... but closing  files resolved my problem

Comment: I'm here because is warnings in generated files. Changing the code is not an option.

Answer (score 11):

Late, but the most obvious is to place in the top of the file

```
#pragma warning disable warning-list
```

Comment: Doesn't help for those pesky generated files.

Answer (score 0):

I had an html file giving 100 warnings that I couldn't change.  I was copying it to the output folder and loading the file using code.  I updated my project to mark the file as an embedded resource and that made the warnings go away.